# Not able to run a Django console after installing a new version of Python in digitalocean Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, terminal, digital-ocean

After uploading to a droplet a Django project I realized that I was using new functionality like f' strings that aren't supported on the 3.5 I proceed to install Python 3.6.3 using this guide:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/

It looks like the installation is successful. When I write "python3 -V" on the console it answers back Python 3.6.3.

When typing "pip freeze" it appears Django==2.0.4 .

The problem comes when typing "python3 manage.py makemigrations" I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: what happen if try `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: Also check `pip -V` for python version that it's for python 3 or python2

Comment: Hi, seuling. pip -V shows (python 3.5) and pip3 -V shows (python 3.6)

Comment: I think your `pip` command is attached to 3.5 and you use `python3` for migrations. So you have to use `pip3` to install.

Comment: Thanks seuling, I was able to make it work thanks to your advice and Daniel's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `pip` is referring to Python 2; you probably need to use `pip3`.